# Using CtrlP isn't giving very good results - am I using it wrong?

Tags: vim

I was hoping that I could just type "job.php" and be directed to the `job.php` in my `/lib/model/` folder, but I've mostly just get many other files returned:

```
[No name]

> batch/dataFixes/jobProspectsSubscriptionId.php
> batch/dataFixes/jobProspectsRankDistance.php
> batch/dataFixes/hiredJobDistanceRankFeedback.php
> batch/sendWeeklyJobOwnersUpdateEmail.php
> batch/dataFixes/backdateJobClosureDailyStats.php
> batch/dataFixes/jobExpectedRevenue.php
> batch/dataFixes/updateJobStats.php
> batch/updateEndedJobState.php
> batch/findUnresponsiveJobPosters.php
> batch/_job_criteria.php

 prt  file  <mru>={ files }=<buf> <->      /Users/shane/Documents/sites/zinc 
>d> job.php_
```

Switching to 'find in path' mode, and typing `lib/model/job.php` brings up tonnes of other classes in that folder which have 'job' in the filename, but not `job.php`.

Job is a pretty common word in our project, but I was hoping that an exact match for the filename would get ranked pretty highly in the results.

Am I using CtrlP wrong, or is the project not really suited to it?

Comment: Maybe cache? Try to type F5 in CtrlP window.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Easiest way is to toggle to file name only mode and regex mode, from docs:

Once inside the prompt:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>:
    Toggle between full-path search and filename only search.
    *Note*: in filename mode, the prompt's base is `>d>` instead of `>>>`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>:
    Toggle between the string mode and full regexp mode.
    *Note*: in full regexp mode, the prompt's base is `r>>` instead of `>>>`

Comment: To set filename-search as your default search mode, add this to your vimrc: `let g:ctrlp_by_filename = 1`

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to your ~/.vimrc (you may need to create if it does not exist):

```
let g:ctrlp_regexp = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually use CtrlP C matching extension `ctrlp-cmatcher`

Its quite a bit faster, and results are what one would expect (without having to use regex).